# Proguard causing RuntimeException (Unmarshalling unknown type code) in Parcelable class

Tags: android

I get this exception if I leave my app and open it after some time. My main activity consist of a ViewPager with three different fragments. I also do some stuff in Application class which I don't think relates to the problem.

This is the exception:

> RuntimeException (@Parcel:readValue:2065) {Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.emu/com.emu.ActivityMain}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@419526d0:
>   Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131361816 at offset 332}

I see lots of this exception happening on users phones in google analytics. All of them are the same except number after readValue and hex number after @ which are 2065 and 419526d0 in above exception.

The exception doesn't point any line of code. I searched about this and it seems it relates to wrong writing to parcel. Although I don't have any parcel in my MainActivity. I don't know what may cause this.

--- EDIT ------------------------------------------------------------------------

I reproduced the exception. It happens when App is leaved with home button, and got cleared from memory after opening some other memory consuming app. When starting it again exception happens. Till now I was thinking that closing app from recent task or from DDMS have the same effect but apparently it doesn't.

@EricWoodruf helped me to find that parcel is somewhere in imported library. I find the parcel in PagerSlidingTabStrip which I had downloaded from web. This is the parcel related code, but I don't really know what is wrong here:

```
public class PagerSlidingTabStrip extends HorizontalScrollView
{
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)
    {
        SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
        currentPosition = savedState.currentPosition;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()
    {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
        savedState.currentPosition = currentPosition;
        return savedState;
    }

    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState
    {
        int currentPosition;

        public SavedState(Parcelable superState)
        {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in)
        {
            super(in);
            currentPosition = in.readInt();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags)
        {
            super.writeToParcel(parcel, flags);
            parcel.writeInt(currentPosition);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>()
        {
            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in)
            {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState[] newArray(int size)
            {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---- EDIT 2 -----------------------------------------------------------------

After I could reproduce the problem I found out that this happens only in Artifact which is signed by my key and proguarded! The debug one doesn't have the problem!

**I disabled proguard on artifact and it works like a charm without the exception. But, what proguard do that result in this problem?**

I tried adding this to proguard but didn't work:

```
-keep class toolfa.android.base.ui.PagerSlidingTabStrip { *; }
-dontwarn toolfa.android.base.ui.PagerSlidingTabStrip
```

this is my current proguard config:

```
-keep class com.nineoldandroids.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.nineoldandroids.**

-keep class ir.adad.** { *; }
-dontwarn ir.adad.**

-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**

-keep class toolfa.android.base.ui.PagerSlidingTabStrip { *; }
-dontwarn toolfa.android.base.ui.PagerSlidingTabStrip

-keep class toolfa.android.sega.ActivityEmulator { *; }
-keep class toolfa.android.sega.Zip { *; }
```

Comment: It is a little hard to help you with such common error without seeing any code... :/

Comment: Do you have any custom classes implementing parcelable?

Comment: BTW you would expect the number after @ to be different because that maps to an object id and may be a memory address.

Comment: @EricWoodruf Actually I have wrote all of the code (parcel free) except android support library and a PagerSlidingTabStrip from somewhere on net. As PagerSlidingTabStrip is a small paging component for viewpager I couldn't believe it's using parcel. But your comment ring me a bell and I checked it out and yes, parcel there is. I will add the code to the question.

Comment: The parcel code looks fine. Should you find a way the reproduce the exception, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19974782/318508) might help to find the exact reason. Does your PagerSlidingTabStrip have a unique ID?

Comment: @MártonMolnár The problem is exception occurs once in a while. I can't reproduce. Yes, I just have one PagerSlidingTabStrip through the app.

Comment: @Ali Can you add the ProGuard config? Maybe it obfuscates the CREATOR member so the superclass one is used?

Comment: @MártonMolnár I didn't add anything special to proguard config, but I will insert the config into question.

Comment: Try adding this: `-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}` See the official recommended configuration [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html) (cannot link directly, click Manual at the bottom, then Examples, then #7 Complete Android application).

Comment: @MártonMolnár yes, it worked. Thank you so much. It was really bad exception as it only happened in artifact and there was no clue. Please add it as an answer so I can give you the bounty!

Comment: I don't see implements in the edit that shows the class definition.  I'm totally confused by the solution.

Comment: I have the same problem , but when I try to build apk, with   minifyEnabled true in release, I get exception : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease, if I set  minifyEnabled false, I'm able to build apk

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As we found out in the comments, the exception was the result of [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) obfuscating Parcelable classes. The fix is to include this snippet in the ProGuard configuration file:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```

*I guess the specific problem here was that ProGuard obfuscated the `CREATOR` member of `PagerSlidingTabStrip`, but since `SavedState` is a subclass of [`View.BaseSavedState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.BaseSavedState.html), the superclass member was still available (this is why it didn't throw a [`BadParcelableException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BadParcelableException.html)), but that uses a different data structure and didn't write the custom attributes into the `Parcel` output.*

There is a recommended configuration for Android applications available in the [ProGuard Manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication), with detailed explanation about entries. For example, it includes that you should keep all class names used in the manifest or other XML files.

Comment: I have the same issue, but proguared causes other problems, is there any other way to fix this problem?

Comment: I am not using any parcels. why does this crash happen to me?

Comment: Bummer, I already have that line in my proguard-rules-save.pro file, but I am still getting this crash.

Comment: I removed the pro-guard line from gradle and it fixed the issue. Thanks for the answer man.

Comment: Excellent find.  Almost nine years after you answered this question, it saved me from a lot of grief.  Thank you!