# Parcel android.os.Parcel: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131231007 at offset 548

Tags: android, gradle, unmarshalling, parcel

My apk built by gradle has a problem ,but built by eclipse does not have.But it dose not happen to every body. I didn't meet this problem. But some of my users met this problem.
you can see the line :

at com.coohuaclient.ui.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:30)

My code of this line is :

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
I have no idea why the gradle has this problem. Please help me

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.coohuaclient/com.coohuaclient.ui.activity.HomeActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@41301c78: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131231007 at offset 548
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@41301c78: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131231007 at offset 548
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2032)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1687)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2022)
at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1240)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:845)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1088)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1070)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(SourceFile:1856)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:210)
at com.coohuaclient.ui.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:30)
at com.coohuaclient.ui.activity.HomeActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:67)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
... 11 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@41301c78: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131231007 at offset 548
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2032)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1687)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2022)
at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1240)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:845)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1088)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1070)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(SourceFile:1856)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:210)
at com.coohuaclient.ui.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:30)
at com.coohuaclient.ui.activity.HomeActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:67)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix Unmarshalling unknown type code XXX at offset YYY in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844945/how-to-fix-unmarshalling-unknown-type-code-xxx-at-offset-yyy-in-android)