# Parcel android.os.Parcel Unmarshalling unknown type code 7209057 at offset XXXX in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization, unmarshalling, parcelable

I have two differents devices :

- Phone Sony Xperia SP Android v4.3
- Tablet Archos 101 helium Android v4.4

When i start my app on the tablet, it's work perfectly.

So i try to launch my app on my the other device(Sony). On this device i have an error when i try to recuperate a parcelable object from an intent in activy.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.*/com.*.activity.QRCodeScanResultActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@419f2ef8: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7209057 at offset 9620
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@419f2ef8: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7209057 at offset 9620
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2288)
        at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1170)
        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:4525)
        at com.*.activity.QRCodeScanResultActivity.onCreate(QRCodeScanResultActivity.java:61)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

It's stange because when the app is launch on my tablet(Archos) for the same action i don't have any problem or error. The problem appaer when i try to get the parcelable objet with `intent.getParcelableExtra` on the activity launch by the intent.

You can see my parcelable class just below :

```
public class BeanFDRQRCode implements Parcelable {

    public String A_Adresse;
    public String A_CDC;
    public String A_Code;
    public String A_ServeurRH;
    public String A_Telephone;

    public String D_CodeEmploi;
    public String D_Matricule;
    public String D_NomPrenom;
    public String D_TauxHoraire;
    public String D_TauxIK;
    public String D_VehImmat;
    public String D_VehPTAC;

    public String F_ID;
    public String F_CodeCouleur;
    public String F_Depart;
    public String F_Duree;
    public String F_Fin;
    public String F_Frais;
    public String F_No_Annee;
    public String F_No_Semaine;
    public String F_Numero;
    public String F_Numero_Remplacee;
    public String F_Poids;
    public String F_Rechargement;
    public String F_Remuneration;
    public String F_Statut;
    public String F_CoStatut;
    public List<String> F_Taches;
    public List<String> F_Secteurs;

    public BeanFDRQRCode() {
        this.F_Taches = new ArrayList<>();
        this.F_Secteurs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeString(A_Adresse);
        out.writeString(A_CDC);
        out.writeString(A_Code);
        out.writeString(A_ServeurRH);
        out.writeString(A_Telephone);

        out.writeString(D_CodeEmploi);
        out.writeString(D_Matricule);
        out.writeString(D_NomPrenom);
        out.writeString(D_TauxHoraire);
        out.writeString(D_TauxIK);
        out.writeString(D_VehImmat);
        out.writeString(D_VehPTAC);

        out.writeString(F_ID);
        out.writeString(F_CodeCouleur);
        out.writeString(F_Depart);
        out.writeString(F_Duree);
        out.writeString(F_Fin);
        out.writeString(F_Frais);
        out.writeString(F_No_Annee);
        out.writeString(F_No_Semaine);
        out.writeString(F_Numero);
        out.writeString(F_Numero_Remplacee);
        out.writeString(F_Poids);
        out.writeString(F_Rechargement);
        out.writeString(F_Remuneration);
        out.writeString(F_Statut);
        out.writeString(F_CoStatut);
        out.writeStringList(F_Taches);
        out.writeStringList(F_Secteurs);
    }

    public static final Creator<BeanFDRQRCode> CREATOR = new Creator<BeanFDRQRCode>() {
        public BeanFDRQRCode createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BeanFDRQRCode(in);
        }

        public BeanFDRQRCode[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BeanFDRQRCode[size];
        }
    };

    private BeanFDRQRCode(Parcel in) {
        A_Adresse = in.readString();
        A_CDC = in.readString();
        A_Code = in.readString();
        A_ServeurRH = in.readString();
        A_Telephone = in.readString();

        D_CodeEmploi = in.readString();
        D_Matricule = in.readString();
        D_NomPrenom = in.readString();
        D_TauxHoraire = in.readString();
        D_TauxIK = in.readString();
        D_VehImmat = in.readString();
        DISTRI_VehPTAC = in.readString();

        F_ID = in.readString();
        F_CodeCouleur = in.readString();
        F_Depart = in.readString();
        F_Duree = in.readString();
        F_Fin = in.readString();
        F_Frais = in.readString();
        F_No_Annee = in.readString();
        F_No_Semaine = in.readString();
        F_Numero = in.readString();
        F_Numero_Remplacee = in.readString();
        F_Poids = in.readString();
        F_Rechargement = in.readString();
        F_Remuneration = in.readString();
        F_Statut = in.readString();
        F_CoStatut = in.readString();
        F_Taches = new ArrayList<>();
        in.readStringList(F_Taches);
        F_Secteurs = new ArrayList<>();
        in.readStringList(F_Secteurs);
    }
}
```

here you can see the creation of my intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(QRCodeScanActivity.this, QRCodeScanResultActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("BeanFDRQRCode", mBeanFDRQRCode);
                    intent.putExtra("androidPrincipal", mAndroidPrincipal);
                    intent.putExtra("beanEnregistrerSignature", beanEnregistrerSignature);
                    QRCodeScanActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

and below this is how i get parcelable from extra :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("onCreate", "QRCodeScanResultActivity");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_result);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        v_BeanFDRQRCode = i.getParcelableExtra("BeanFDRQRCode");
        androidPrincipal = i.getParcelableExtra("androidPrincipal");
        beanEnregistrerSignature = i.getParcelableExtra("beanEnregistrerSignature");
```

}

I read lot of things like this [How to fix Unmarshalling unknown type code XXX at offset YYY in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844945/how-to-fix-unmarshalling-unknown-type-code-xxx-at-offset-yyy-in-android)

But my problem is particullary because the app work on the tablet(Archos).

I find nothing to solve my problem, morever i don't understand why the probleme depending on the device.

Answer (score 0):

As we found out in the comments, the exception was the result of ProGuard obfuscating Parcelable classes. The fix is to include this snippet in the ProGuard configuration file:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```

[Source answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21380449/2413972)

Comment: i have add this to my ProGuard configuration file **proguard-rules.pro** with this in my build.gradle `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` but it's not working