java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key in ArrayMap: null (in Android SDK)
We get this error and we cannot reproduce it.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key in ArrayMap: null
    at android.util.ArrayMap.validate()(ArrayMap.java:688)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal()(Parcel.java:3587)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked()(BaseBundle.java:292)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel()(BaseBundle.java:236)
    at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray()(Bundle.java:1079)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState()(PhoneWindow.java:2265)
    at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState()(Activity.java:1719)
    at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState()(Activity.java:1672)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState()(Instrumentation.java:1356)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity()(ActivityThread.java:3869)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence()(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath()(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState()(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute()(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage()(ActivityThread.java:2317)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop()(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main()(ActivityThread.java:8625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()(Method.java:-2)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()(ZygoteInit.java:1130)

What's more, we even checked all the potential spots in our code which use Parcels and we didn't find out any flaws in our implementation. Do you have any ideas on what can be wrong or where to find the answer?

Where do you see this exception? What happened before the exception? Does it happen on specific devices?

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588311/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-duplicate-key-in-arraymap-null

@JensV We can see crashes on prod in New Relic (a monitoring tool such as Crashlytics). The thing is we cannot reproduce it so that's why we don't know the exact place in the code. What we know is that this happens for all Android devices with OS below Android 13 (exclusively). It's rather not duplicate since in my stacktrace you can see that the crash happens on Android SDK internals only.
