# Xamarin Android Unfortunately App has Stopped

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Android to develop an Android Application.

I'm trying to catch global exceptions through

```
AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += (sender, args) =>
            {
               //WRITE TO FILE
            };
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
            {
                /*
                 * When a background thread crashes this is the code that will be executed. You can
                 * recover from this.
                 */
            };
```

I'm still receiving "Unfortunately App has stopped errors" frequently on various devices. The errors are not being caught.

I suspect it is memory leaks but I'm not sure. I can't access the logcat files of the devices on which this error is being raised fairly often. I'm at my wits' end. Could anyone shed some light on the same?

On a side note, if a global exception is raised and caught, the UnhandledExceptionRaiser is interrupted in between and is not written to file (This I guess is because of Android cleaning up the process?)

Comment: @MysticMagic Did you even read the question?

Comment: Yes. I read. I read that, too "The errors are not being caught." But that wouldn't help us in helping you.. So any ways, good luck. :)

Comment: @Alex.F Nope. Tried everything. Still the app is crashing and unhandled exception raiser is not being called. I'm still trying out different ways and hacks to get to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After analyzing Google Crash Reports, I found out the actual error.

```
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.apptimator.pro.mayusha/com.apptimator.mayusha.HomeActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@42ab6ad8: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7209057 at offset 1064

......
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@42ab6ad8: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7209057 at offset 1064
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2038)
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835):     at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1237)
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1969)
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835):     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:977)
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:949)
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1155)
11-12 22:36:31.410: E/AndroidRuntime(4835):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
```

This error can be caused by either [this ("Proguard Causing Runtime exception")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342700/proguard-causing-runtimeexception-unmarshalling-unknown-type-code-in-parcelabl) or in this Xamarin Android case, by android failing to restore saved instance state due to nested save state implementations.

I was using SlidingMenuSharp ([SlidingMenuSharp link)](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/SlidingMenuSharp) library in Home Activity which was implementing IParcelable and was using nested SavedState class. Same error can be found [here](https://github.com/LordZoltan/PagerSlidingTabStrip.Net/commit/0e76057ec4890cad3c51ac082b771084a907bc3f)

Nevertheless, I managed to fix it and its all working fine now. To fix the error, please follow the mentioned Bundle implementation for SavedState, OnRestoreInstanceState and OnSaveInstanceState

```
public class SavedState : BaseSavedState
    {
        public int Item { get; private set; }

        public SavedState(IParcelable superState)
            : base(superState)
        {

        }

        public SavedState(Parcel parcel)
            : base(parcel)
        {
            Item = parcel.ReadInt();
        }

        public override void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
        {
            base.WriteToParcel(dest, flags);
            dest.WriteInt(Item);
        }

        [ExportField("CREATOR")]
        static SavedStateCreator InitializeCreator()
        {
            return new SavedStateCreator();
        }

        class SavedStateCreator : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
        {
            public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
            {
                return new SavedState(source);
            }

            public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
            {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRestoreInstanceState(IParcelable state)
    {
        try
        {
            Bundle bundle = state as Bundle;
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                IParcelable superState = (IParcelable)bundle.GetParcelable("base");
                if (superState != null)
                    base.OnRestoreInstanceState(superState);
                _viewAbove.SetCurrentItem(bundle.GetInt("currentPosition", 0));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            base.OnRestoreInstanceState(state);
            // Ignore, this needs to support IParcelable...
        }
    }

    protected override IParcelable OnSaveInstanceState()
    {
        var superState = base.OnSaveInstanceState();
        Bundle state = new Bundle();
        state.PutParcelable("base", superState);
        state.PutInt("currentPosition", _viewAbove.GetCurrentItem());

        return state;
    }
```

Comment: This also apply to CirclePageIndicator from Xamarin samples - their implementation of OnRestoreInstanceState and OnSaveInstanceState crash on "Unmarshalling unknown type code", your approach works

Comment: @rouen Please report it to them/create a pull request :)

Comment: After viewing this solution, I realized I should restart the device, which fixed the issue for me.  Not sure if it's the same issue.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Not sure about the restart approach. You can't rely on the user to restart the device. Nevertheless, this issue was confirmed and a pull request was accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` as way to intercept unhandled exceptions, as mentioned in the Xamarin [docs](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=E:Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser):

> Note: You cannot rely on the AppDomain.UnhandledException event as
>   managed exceptions are never unhandled in MonoDroid; they are always
>   intercepted at the Android/managed boundary within a catch(Exception)
>   block.

I would suggest to keep on using `AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser` and keep the operations there as efficient as possible.

Also exceptions that occur in background threads and not observed (and don't cause an unhandled exceptions) can be caught with `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`.

And lastly, I subscribe to all of the exception handling events in my application class (the class that inherits from Android.App.Application) because it's the first entry point of the app and you can have exceptions even before your main activity starts (or wherever you are subscribing from now)

P.S. I also use `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` just to be on the safe side but never caught any exception with it yet.

Comment: I'm using AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser in my Application class. And I have just put in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException to be on the safe side.