# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel: Unmarshalling unknown type code

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I seem to be getting a strange error in my app (see [GitHub](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/FlashcardsApp)), which occurs when I pass objects to different activities that implement `Parcelable`.

I have checked other questions and answers here on Stack Overflow, but I was unable to find a solution. I've tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21380449/4230345), for example - here it is for reference:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```

I've also made sure that the method calls in `writeToParcel` are in order. Most other questions on Stack Overflow about this issue don't have answers.

Moreover, the reason I am asking a new question is because I think my problem is caused because of how I have used interfaces in my app (I will expand on this point later on). Other questions on Stack Overflow would not suit my particular scenario.

In the following, I have provided links to the code via GitHub, so that you can explore more of the code if required.

---

When I click on a button to [launch a new activity](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/FlashcardsApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/satsumasoftware/flashcards/ui/FlashCardActivity.java#L71) (passing an object that implements `Parcelable`), [there is a crash](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/FlashcardsApp/issues/16):

```
Process: com.satsuware.flashcards, PID: 4664
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.satsuware.flashcards/com.satsumasoftware.flashcards.ui.FlashCardActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@d2219e4: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6815860 at offset 200
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    ...
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@d2219e4: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6815860 at offset 200
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2319)
at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2633)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1914)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2592)
at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:786)
at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:5377)
at com.satsumasoftware.flashcards.ui.FlashCardActivity.onCreate(FlashCardActivity.java:71)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
...
```

I call the aforementioned activity like so (also [see GitHub](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/FlashcardsApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/satsumasoftware/flashcards/ui/TopicDetailActivity.java#L162)):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TopicDetailActivity.this, FlashCardActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(FlashCardActivity.EXTRA_TOPIC, mTopic);
intent.putExtra(FlashCardActivity.EXTRA_NUM_CARDS, mSelectedNumCards);
intent.putExtra(FlashCardActivity.EXTRA_CARD_LIST, mFilteredCards);
startActivity(intent);
```

The main part to consider is when I pass `mTopic`. This is a [`Topic` *interface*](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/FlashcardsApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/satsumasoftware/flashcards/framework/topic/Topic.java) that I created.

However, the `Topic` interface extends `Parcelable` and so the objects that implement `Topic` also include the constructor, `CREATOR` field, and the methods that a class implementing `Parcelable` would normally have to have.

You can view the relevant classes via the GitHub links, but I will provide the relevant parts of these classes below. Here is the `Topic` interface:

```
public interface Topic extends Parcelable {

    int getId();

    String getIdentifier();

    String getName();

    Course getCourse();


    ArrayList<FlashCard> getFlashCards(Context context);


    class FlashCardsRetriever {

        public static ArrayList<FlashCard> filterStandardCards(ArrayList<FlashCard> flashCards, @StandardFlashCard.ContentType int contentType) {
            ArrayList<FlashCard> filteredCards = new ArrayList<>();
            for (FlashCard flashCard : flashCards) {
                boolean isPaper2 = ((StandardFlashCard) flashCard).isPaper2();
                boolean condition;
                switch (contentType) {
                    case StandardFlashCard.PAPER_1:
                        condition = !isPaper2;
                        break;
                    case StandardFlashCard.PAPER_2:
                        condition = isPaper2;
                        break;
                    case StandardFlashCard.ALL:
                        condition = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("content type '" + contentType + "' is invalid");
                }
                if (condition) filteredCards.add(flashCard);
            }
            return filteredCards;
        }

        ...
    }

}
```

A class (object) that `implements Topic`:

```
public class CourseTopic implements Topic {

    ...

    public CourseTopic(int id, String identifier, String name, Course course) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return mIdentifier;
    }

    ...


    protected CourseTopic(Parcel in) {
        mId = in.readInt();
        mIdentifier = in.readString();
        mName = in.readString();
        mCourse = in.readParcelable(Course.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CourseTopic> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CourseTopic>() {
        @Override
        public CourseTopic createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CourseTopic(in);
        }

        @Override
        public CourseTopic[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CourseTopic[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mId);
        dest.writeString(mIdentifier);
        dest.writeString(mName);
        dest.writeParcelable(mCourse, flags);
    }

}
```

In one of the last lines of the code above, you can see I pass `mCourse`, which is a `Course` object I created. Here it is:

```
public class Course implements Parcelable {

    ...

    public Course(String subject, String examBoard, @FlashCard.CourseType String courseType,
              String revisionGuide) {
        ...
    }


    public String getSubjectIdentifier() {
        return mSubjectIdentifier;
    }

    public String getExamBoardIdentifier() {
        return mBoardIdentifier;
    }

    public ArrayList<Topic> getTopics(Context context) {
        ArrayList<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
        String filename = mSubjectIdentifier + "_" + mBoardIdentifier + "_topics.csv";
        CsvParser parser = CsvUtils.getMyParser();
        try {
            List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(context.getAssets().open(filename));
            for (String[] line : allRows) {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
                topics.add(new CourseTopic(id, line[1], line[2], this));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return topics;
    }

    ...


    protected Course(Parcel in) {
        mSubjectIdentifier = in.readString();
        mBoardIdentifier = in.readString();
        mCourseType = in.readString();
        mRevisionGuide = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Course> CREATOR = new Creator<Course>() {
        @Override
        public Course createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Course(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Course[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Course[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mSubjectIdentifier);
        dest.writeString(mBoardIdentifier);
        dest.writeString(mCourseType);
        dest.writeString(mRevisionGuide);
    }
```

}

I suspect something here may be causing the problem, and is the reason my scenario is different from those in other questions.

---

To be honest, I'm not exactly sure what may be causing the error, so explanations and guidance in answers would be much appreciated.

---

**Edit**:

After *David Wasser*'s suggestions, I have updated parts of my code like so:

FlashCardActivity.java - `onCreate(...)`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
extras.setClassLoader(Topic.class.getClassLoader());
mTopic = extras.getParcelable(EXTRA_TOPIC);
```

Course.java - `writeToParcel(...)`:

```
dest.writeString(mSubjectIdentifier);
dest.writeString(mBoardIdentifier);
dest.writeString(mCourseType);
dest.writeInt(mRevisionGuide == null ? 0 : 1);
if (mRevisionGuide != null) dest.writeString(mRevisionGuide);
```

Course.java - `Course(Parcel in)`:

```
mSubjectIdentifier = in.readString();
mBoardIdentifier = in.readString();
mCourseType = in.readString();
if (in.readInt() != 0) mRevisionGuide = in.readString();
```

I've added log messages using `Log.d(...)` to see if any variables are null when being passed in `writeToParcel(...)` and used *David Wasser*'s method to properly handle this.

I still get the same error message, however.

Comment: Post the code relating to parceling and unparceling for the actual classes that are put in the `Intent`.

Comment: @DavidWasser I've updated my answer to show the code for the classes put in the `Intent` (they can be viewed in full through the GitHub links provided).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your problem is in `LanguagesFlashCard`. Here are your parcel/unparcel methods:

```
protected LanguagesFlashCard(Parcel in) {
    mId = in.readInt();
    mEnglish = in.readString();
    mAnswerPrefix = in.readString();
    mAnswer = in.readString();
    mTier = in.readInt();
    mTopic = in.readParcelable(Topic.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

As you can see, they don't match. The second item you write to the `Parcel` is an `int`, the second item you read from the `Parcel` is a `String`.

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(mId);
    dest.writeInt(mTier);
    dest.writeString(mEnglish);
    dest.writeString(mAnswerPrefix);
    dest.writeString(mAnswer);
    dest.writeParcelable(mTopic, flags);
}
```

Comment: Can the order of values change, if all are of same type. I mean 
 
    mEnglish = in.readString();
    mAnswerPrefix = in.readString(); 
    mAnswer = in.readString();

can be read as 

    dest.writeString(mAnswer);
    dest.writeString(mEnglish);
    dest.writeString(mAnswerPrefix);

Comment: @UsmanRana No. You must read and write the values in exactly the same sequence, no matter what types they are. You are serializing and deserializing to/from a byte array. `Parcel` isn't a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin code for sub data class like ImagesModel also parcelable used

```
data class MyPostModel(
    @SerializedName("post_id") val post_id: String? = "",
    @SerializedName("images") val images: ArrayList<ImagesModel>? = null
): Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.writeString(post_id)
        parcel.createTypedArrayList(ImagesModel.CREATOR)
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(post_id)
        parcel.writeTypedList(images)
    }
}
```