# Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I get following exception while build signed apk file (If I just build application in release, here is no error) :

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:api:assemble, :app:assembleRelease]
Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.2.1 for debug
Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.2.1 for release
Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.2.1 for staging
Warning:com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator: can't find referenced method 'float ceil(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 26.173 secs
Information:1 error
Information:6 warnings
```

here is gradle log :

```
Warning: there were 21 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

what I did, is that I change `proguard-rules.pro` file, to fix exception caused parcel. I found out answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342700/proguard-causing-runtimeexception-unmarshalling-unknown-type-code-in-parcelabl)..

here is how it looks :

```
-keep class com.zzoome.android.Views.TagGroup.**
-dontwarn com.zzoome.android.Views.TagGroup.**

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: So finally you solved the issue ?

Comment: nope, still get the error while trying to build signed apk  :(

Comment: Did u try with _Build - Clean_ ? also set _minifyEnabled false_

Comment: If I set  minifyEnabled false I get no errors, but proguared -rules won't work

Comment: Yes it will be ! did u check this https://github.com/Instagram/ig-json-parser/issues/11?

Comment: I have updated question @Piyush, can you check it? com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator is the main problem, I think

Comment: Yes seems because of it. !

Comment: @Piyush if I set minifyEnabled false , proguard-rules won't be ignored?

Comment: @piyush I am facing same issue after updating android Studio to 2.2.2. Can you please help me how to resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have change proguard-rules :

```
-keep class com.zzoome.android.Views.TagGroup { *; }
-dontwarn com.zzoome.android.Views.TagGroup
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked in my case with the follwing error: app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug

Answer (score -1):

Add these to your proguard-rules file

```
-dontwarn okio.**

-dontwarn com.google.**
```

Similarly add all your libraries .