# Android Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver

Tags: android, service

I have a class ABCReceiver which extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver.

`Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, DEFService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtras(intent);
startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);`

On GalaxyS4 device with OS 4.4.2, I get following exception:

```
`Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.application.ABCReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@2e8c37a4: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7274595 at offset 248
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2426)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@2e8c37a4: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7274595 at offset 248
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2080)
       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314)
       at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
       at android.os.Bundle.putInt(Bundle.java:470)
       at android.content.Intent.putExtra(Intent.java:5553)
       at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService(WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:88)
       at com.application.ABCReceiver.onReceive(LocationReceiver.java:17)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2419)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java`
```

I am unable to reproduce this error. Kindly, help me in understanding what exactly is happening here and how can fix this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342700/proguard-causing-runtimeexception-unmarshalling-unknown-type-code-in-parcelabl it might help

Comment: Thanks Gautam but I have -keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
} in my proguard