# Got error while trying to pass model class arrayList to activity from fragment?

Tags: android, arraylist

Error throws while passing ArrayList to Activity from Fragment. I never got this type of error. The error throws only when I pass ArrayList to Activity.I have searched but I didn't get an answer that solves my problem. Can you please check my code and tell me if I had done any mistake.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@c154e0a:
>   Unmarshalling unknown type code 101 at offset 884
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel
>   android.os.Parcel@c154e0a: Unmarshalling unknown type code 101 at
>   offset 884
>                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2453)
>                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727)
>                                                                       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
>                                                                       at android.os.BaseBundle.getSerializable(BaseBundle.java:1064)
>                                                                       at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:934)
>                                                                       at com.iroid.uiic.ui.main.vehiclelist.vehicle_detail_view.VehicleDetailViewActivity.onCreate(VehicleDetailViewActivity.java:39)
>                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
>                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

**My Fragment Code :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VehicleDetailViewActivity.class);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList("arrayList", arrayVehicleList);
        args.putString("title",arrayVehicleList.get(position).getRegno());
        args.putString("position", String.valueOf(position));
        intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
        startActivity(intent);
```

**My Activity Code :**

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
        arrayVehicleList = (ArrayList<ModelVehicleList>) 
        args.getSerializable("arrayList");
        title = (String) args.getSerializable("title");
        position = (String) args.getSerializable("position");
```

**My Model Class :**

```
public class ModelVehicleList implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String user_id;
    @SerializedName("engine")
    private String engine;
    @SerializedName("odometerreading")
    private String odometerreading;
    @SerializedName("vehiclecolor")
    private String vehiclecolor;
    @SerializedName("regno")
    private String regno;
    @SerializedName("previousinsuranceNo")
    private String previousinsuranceNo;
    @SerializedName("previouspolicy")
    private String previouspolicy;
    @SerializedName("previousNCB")
    private String previousNCB;

    @SerializedName("frondimage")
    private String frondimage;
    @SerializedName("rearimage")
    private String rearimage;
    @SerializedName("leftimage")
    private String leftimage;
    @SerializedName("rightimage")
    private String rightimage;
    @SerializedName("speedometerimage")
    private String speedometerimage;
    @SerializedName("topimage")
    private String topimage;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("date")
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("time")
    private String time;
    @SerializedName("remarks")
    private String remarks;




    public static final Creator<ModelVehicleList> CREATOR = new Creator<ModelVehicleList>() {
        @Override
        public ModelVehicleList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ModelVehicleList(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ModelVehicleList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ModelVehicleList[size];
        }
    };

    public ModelVehicleList(Parcel in) {
        user_id = in.readString();
        status = in.readString();
        date = in.readString();
        time = in.readString();
       // remarks = in.readString();

        engine = in.readString();
        odometerreading = in.readString();
        vehiclecolor = in.readString();
        regno = in.readString();
        previousinsuranceNo = in.readString();
        previouspolicy = in.readString();
        previousNCB = in.readString();

        frondimage = in.readString();
        rearimage = in.readString();
        speedometerimage = in.readString();
        leftimage = in.readString();
        rightimage = in.readString();
        topimage = in.readString();


    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

        parcel.writeString(status);
        parcel.writeString(date);
        parcel.writeString(time);
        parcel.writeString(remarks);

        parcel.writeString(user_id);

        parcel.writeString(engine);
        parcel.writeString(odometerreading);
        parcel.writeString(vehiclecolor);
        parcel.writeString(regno);
        parcel.writeString(previousinsuranceNo);
        parcel.writeString(previouspolicy);
        parcel.writeString(previousNCB);

        parcel.writeString(frondimage);
        parcel.writeString(rearimage);
        parcel.writeString(speedometerimage);
        parcel.writeString(leftimage);
        parcel.writeString(rightimage);
        parcel.writeString(topimage);
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public String getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public String getOdometerreading() {
        return odometerreading;
    }

    public String getVehiclecolor() {
        return vehiclecolor;
    }

    public String getRegno() {
        return regno;
    }

    public String getPreviousinsuranceNo() {
        return previousinsuranceNo;
    }

    public String getPreviouspolicy() {
        return previouspolicy;
    }

    public String getPreviousNCB() {
        return previousNCB;
    }

    public String getFrondimage() {
        return frondimage;
    }

    public String getRearimage() {
        return rearimage;
    }

    public String getLeftimage() {
        return leftimage;
    }

    public String getRightimage() {
        return rightimage;
    }

    public String getSpeedometerimage() {
        return speedometerimage;
    }

    public String getTopimage() {
        return topimage;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to you to use `Parcelable` ?

Comment: This should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342700/proguard-causing-runtimeexception-unmarshalling-unknown-type-code-in-parcelabl

Comment: The sequence of reading and writing to parcel have to be same. You are writing status to parcel first but reading user_id first. That is what making JVM to throw this error

Comment: Yes I trying to pass an ArrayList, that,s why I use Parceable.

Comment: @JayeshM you can pass `ArrayList` with serializable, just implement it in data class

Comment: @JayeshM And another one. You are using `putParcelableArrayList()`  but to get list using `getSerializable()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VehicleDetailViewActivity.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelableArrayList("arrayList", arrayVehicleList);
args.putString("title",arrayVehicleList.get(position).getRegno());
args.putString("position", String.valueOf(position));
intent.putExtras(args);
startActivity(intent);
```

My Activity Code :

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Bundle args = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 arrayVehicleList = (ArrayList<ModelVehicleList>) 
 args.getParcelableArrayListExtra("arrayList");
 title = (String) args.getStringExtra("title");
 position = (String) args.getStringExtra("position");
```