# Android: Parcelable exception

Tags: android, parcelable

I am getting following exception in production environment. It is related with parcelable classes. But it is not showing which class is problematic. Below is detailed log trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.app/in.app.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@ae3c90f: Unmarshalling unknown type code -15962911 at offset 816
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

It is happening in `onStart` of Activity. I am not passing any parcelable object to the activity. It is launcher one. 
How can I find which parcelable is there at specifed
`Unmarshalling unknown type code -15962911 at offset 816`
Also as per Crashlytics, Device status is as follows:
100% Proximity on
3% App in background
It is happening on multiple OS versions.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements CleanUpDelegate,
    OnFilterAppliedListener,
    UpdatePhoneNoDialog.UpdatePhoneNoListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GenericDialogOperationListener,
    DAPopupFragment.DAPopupOperationsListener,
    OnLoginListener, HomeScreenFragmentV2.showECOOrderPopup, BottomNavigationRVAdapter.BottomNavigationItemClick

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createBottomNavigation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you got this in a production environment I'm almost sure it's related to ProGuard. Since you aren't using any self-made parcelable class it's most likely a library. What you could try is go through your library's GitHub page and see if you have included their ProGuard rules.

Comment: post your main activity code

Comment: @VivekMishra Main Activity code added. Since class is very large so I added only relevant methods

Comment: Are you writing anything in to a `Bundle` in `onSaveInstanceState()`?

Comment: post your model(Pojo class) its due to your Parcelable arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is happening in production, high probability is it is because of [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) obfuscating Parcelable classes.

Try including this in your ProGuard config file:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
     static ** CREATOR;
}
```

For further info, there is a recommended configuration for Android applications available in the [ProGuard Manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#androidapplication), with detailed explanation about entries.

Comment: Is there any way find the unknown type code `unknown type code -15962911`. And this majorly happening on Oreo.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342700/proguard-causing-runtimeexception-unmarshalling-unknown-type-code-in-parcelabl). I am not sure how to find the unknown type but this question might help you replicate the issue and get more info

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> Unmarshalling unknown type code XXXXX at offset XXXXX

Happens when you have an object that implements `Parcelable` that is malformed.

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyClass> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyClass>(){

    @Override
    public MyClass createFromParcel(Parcel source){
        // The most common issues are in this constructor.
        return new MyClass(source);
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass[] newArray(int size){
        return new MyClass[size];
    }
}
```

When you `Parcelable` object needs to be recreated the `return new MyClass(source);` (using the above example) will be called. And this is where the most common issues happen:

1. You have a variable on a certain type, and you are unmarshalling it as another type.

**Example:** you have a variable `id` that is from the type long and you are reading it like this `id = source.readInt();`

2. You are trying to read a value that is not available in your `Parcelable`.

**Example:** You try to `id = source.readInt();` but you forgot to `dest.writeInt(id);`

3. Your `Parcelable` extends from another object that is also `Parcelable` and you forgot to call super in the read and write methods.

**Example:**

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // This is missing
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
}
```

4. Missing proguard rule:

This will preserve the special fields of all Parcelable implementations:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
     static ** CREATOR;
}
```

---

**tl;dr** This is pretty difficult to find what is the issue without all the source code. So my suggestion to you is that you check all your `Parcelable` objects that you are using in the activities you mention and check if they are well formed.